# cron cannot run composer

Tags: cron, cron-task

I setup composer by following this guide: http://codybonney.com/installing-composer-globally-on-centos-6-4/

it is ok. I could run composer globally.

The problem is that I want to run composer update with cron job.

05 15 * * * cd ~/myproject && composer update --no-dev >  ~/composer.tx

error: /bin/sh: composer: command not found

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using full path to composer installed folder

05 15 * * * cd ~/myproject && /usr/local/bin/composer update --no-dev > ~/composer.tx

Comment: you can leave out the  `cd ~/myproject &&`  if you do it like that, because you already specify the full path.  The issue is that you can not run a command  in a folder without a path, so you have to write either the full path or add `./` ,     like `cd /your/folder && ./composer` , as  I proposed before.  (btw, this is unrelated to composer )

Answer (score 0):

/bin/sh  is probably not the shell you normally use (bash), and it probably has different path settings.

Add the full path to the command so you don't need to change dirs

```
05 15 * * *  /home/user/myproject/composer
```

...or write your command like `./composer`

Comment: sorry but I found the answer. somehome cron cannot run global composer command. I have to write the full path to composer installation folder. e.g /usr/local/bin/composer. then everything fine